# java word search diagonally

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, diagonal, wordsearch

so I've been working on this for hours but i cant seem to figure out how the heck to search through a 2D charr array diagonally. Some context for this, I have figured out how to do the search both vertically and horizontally. Also, I am expected to find words from all 4 directions diagonally (top left -> bottom right/ bottom right -> top left/top right -> bottom left/top right -> bottom left)
Here's what I got so far

```
public void searchDiagonal() {
    char [][] grid = //is a [15][15] array
    char[] sample = {'W','O','R','D'}
    int startR = 0;
    int startC = 0;
    int endR = 0;
    int endC = 0;
    boolean wordFound = false;
    int row = 0;
    for(int i = grid.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(i == grid.length - 1) {
                //check the middle diagonal
                for(int j = grid.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

                    int index = 0;
                    if(sample[index] == grid[j][j])
                    {
                        startR = j;
                        startC = j;
                        if(index == sample.length - 1) {
                            //word has been found
                            endR = j;
                            endC = j;
                            wordFound = true;
                            System.out.println("Word found at [" + startR + "][" + startC + "] & ["
                                    + endR + "][" + endC + "]");
                            break;
                        }
                        index++;
                    }
                    if(wordFound)
                        break;
                }
        }
    }
    for(int i = grid.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for(int j = grid.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {

        }
            //now i will handle up/down and row will handle left/right [row][i]
            if(i == 13) {
                row = 14;
            }

            int index = 0;
            if(sample[index] == grid[row][i])
            {

                if(index == 0) {
                    startR = row;
                    startC = i;
                }
                //first char matches
                if(sample.length - 1 == index) {
                    endR = row;
                    endxC = i;
                    wordFound = true;
                    SSystem.out.println("Word found at [" + startR + "][" + startC + "] & ["
                                    + endR + "][" + endC + "]");
                    break;
                }
                index++;
            }
            row--;
        }

}
```

Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

To find out 4 diagonal words i would try following

1. Find TopLeftBottomRight word
2. reverse it
3. Find TopRightBottomLeft word
4. reverse it
5. find the sample word in above word lists.

Working code for find all 4 diagonal words

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] testData = {{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}, {'e', 'c', 'b', 'e'}, {'h', 'g', 'a', 'm'}, {'w', 'x', 'z', 't'}};
        char[] sample = {'c', 'a', 't'};
        boolean result = findInDiagonalWords(diagonalWords(testData),sample);
        System.out.println(result);
    }


    private static List<String> diagonalWords(char[][] testData) {
        String first = topLeftBottomRight(testData);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(first);
        String second = sb.reverse().toString();

        String third = bottomLeftTopRight(testData);
        StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
        sb1.append(third);
        String fourth = sb1.reverse().toString();

        return Arrays.asList(first, second, third, fourth);
    }

    private static String topLeftBottomRight(char[][] testData) {
        String topLeftBottomRight = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < testData.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++) {
                if (i == j) {
                    topLeftBottomRight = topLeftBottomRight + testData[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return topLeftBottomRight;
    }

    private static String bottomLeftTopRight(char[][] testData) {
        String bottomLeftTopRight = "";
        for (int i = testData.length; i > 0; i--) {
            for (int j = 0; j < testData.length; j++) {
                if ((testData.length - i) == j) {
                    bottomLeftTopRight = bottomLeftTopRight + testData[i - 1][j];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return bottomLeftTopRight;
    }

    private static boolean findInDiagonalWords(List<String> diagonalWords, char[] sample) {
        // return true if sample lies in diagonal words
        //return false;
    }
}
```